# Ruby and SHA256 - Difference between MacOS and Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, macos, sha256

I wrote this little test script in Ruby (on MacOS):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'digest/sha2'

def calc_sha(file)
  # calc hash
  hash = Digest::SHA2.new
  File.open(file, 'r') do |fh|
    fh.each_line do |l|
      hash << l
    end
  end

  hash.to_s
end

puts calc_sha('dont-panic.jpeg')
puts '40075d8441ab6a9abeceb7039552704320f471667b8f9ac3c18b9b5b0a1fee7e'
puts calc_sha('dont-panic.jpeg') ==  '40075d8441ab6a9abeceb7039552704320f471667b8f9ac3c18b9b5b0a1fee7e'
```

Which outputs (on MacOS):

```
~/shatest $ ./sha.rb 
40075d8441ab6a9abeceb7039552704320f471667b8f9ac3c18b9b5b0a1fee7e
40075d8441ab6a9abeceb7039552704320f471667b8f9ac3c18b9b5b0a1fee7e
true
```

Then I run the exact same Script in Windows XP:

```
F:\shatest>ruby sha.rb
9c787b71392551238b24915c888dbd44f4ff465c8e8aadca7af3bb6aaf66a3ca
40075d8441ab6a9abeceb7039552704320f471667b8f9ac3c18b9b5b0a1fee7e
false
```

Can anyone tell me whats the Problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening a *JPEG* (i.e. a binary file) and then reading every *line of text* from it. Don't do that. Any time you treat binary data as text, you're just asking for odd behaviour.

I don't know much about Ruby at all, but I'd generally expect to open the file, and repeatedly read chunks of *binary* data from it, updating the hash with that. Don't do anything which talks about "lines" or uses text at all.

Comment: i'm now using: Digest::SHA256.file('dont-panic.jpeg').hexdigest ... looks like a much better method for binary files